# private npm registry has old package version

Tags: npm

I have to work with a private npm package installed inside a company.
When I run `npm install` I'm getting an npm error `npm ERR! No compatible version found`.

Is there a way to ask/force a mirror of a package to private npm registry?
I'm not the admin of the private registry.

Comment: I think this is more of a question for your network administrator, or whoever manages the registry.

Comment: I agree, I hoped to gain more information about how to solve such problem because the other version of the same public package did get into the private registry.